# how to combine 2 Linq predicates -C#

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-sql

i have the following function

```
public virtual ICollection<T> initData<T>(System.Data.Entity.DbSet<T> set, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter) where T : CModel<T>
        {
            var x = (from dc in set select dc);
            if (!this.db.valid)
            {
                System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T, bool>> active = a => a.active;
                filter = (Expression<Func<T, bool>>)Expression.Lambda(Expression.AndAlso(filter, active));
                x.Where(filter);

            }
            else
            {
                x.Where(filter);
            }
            return (ICollection<T>)x.ToList();
        }
```

when ever i try to combine the 2 predicates with `AndAlso` i throws an exception :

```
The binary operator AndAlso is not defined for the types 'System.Func`2[namespace.Models.MyClass,System.Boolean]' and 'System.Func`2[namespace.Models.MyClass,System.Boolean]'.
```

how can i combine these two conditions?

Comment: You can use predicate builder for that. 
http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

Comment: [LINQ to Entities: Combining Predicates](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/meek/archive/2008/05/02/linq-to-entities-combining-predicates.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are making life hard for yourself.  You could just use the Where extension method multiple times like this:

```
public virtual ICollection<T> initData<T>(System.Data.Entity.DbSet<T> set, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter) where T : CModel<T>
{
    var x = (from dc in set select dc);
    x = set.Where(filter);

    if (!this.db.valid)
    {
        x = x.Where(a => a.active);
    }

    return x.ToList();
}
```

Note that in your code you used `x.Where(filter);`
This is useless because Where does not mutate x, so the result is basically discarded. 
To keep the result you need to assign it to something: 
`x = x.Where(filter);`.
This is the same idea as when you are working with strings.

**Second answer:**

There is a built in delegate called `Predicate<T>`.  I think you might have more luck using this type than the `Func<T, bool>`, even though they both essentially have the same meaning.  I think that be what the compiler error was trying to say.